# Is there a library to convert C++ expressions to MathML or similar?

Tags: c++

I have many calculations in my program. Now I want to convert these caculations to formulas that can be part of reports and documentation (PDF). I want to be 100% certain that the reports match the actual code. What I don't want to do is parse the code myself.

In proof-of-concepts I created classes that contain both the value and the string of an expression.

```
Expression a("a", 7);
Expression b("b", 3);
Expression c("c");
c = a * b;
std::cout << c.formula() << std::endl; // would print "c = a * b"
```

I don't want to handle all cases, such as if, loops, ... myself. So is there a library that can do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Most ways of representing a formula don't have concise representations of every kind of C++ control flow structure.  What more, C++ "math" isn't the same as abstract mathematical equations; C++ default integer math is bounded, floating point math isn't real numbers, etc.

You'd probably be better off removing the mathematics from the C++ code entirely.  There are computing platforms that can produce formatted representations of their mathematics as part of their feature set.

This also depends on the kind of mathematics you are doing.  If you are doing abstract algebra, you'd probably use a different program or engine than if you where doing number crunching simulations.

If you don't want to use a 3rd party program, what I would do in your situation is write my own domain specific language, and either parse it or use expression templates to build it, and then use the expression tree in two ways (one for computation and the other for display).  My approach would probably be a bit different than what you are describing, but that is probably my abstract mathematics bias showing through.

Unless I am doing a LOT of calculation (like, many kilobytes of equations), the reliability of this would probably be lower than just transcribing the formulas.